# how to use a package with dependencies with different version numbers than what my app use in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I want to use package date_util.dart in my app. my pubspec.yaml file is

```
name: personal_expenses
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: "none" 
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  date_utils: ^0.1.4
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/waiting.png  
  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Quicksand
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

when I save it, I receive this error:

```
[personal_expenses] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in personal_expenses...               
Because personal_expenses depends on date_utils ^0.1.4 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because personal_expenses depends on date_utils ^0.1.4 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

I try it by different available versions of date_util and none of them worked. I also download date_utils 0.1.4 on my system but I don't know how to use a downloaded package in my app! anyway, pubspec.yaml file of date_utils 0.1.4 is:

```
name: date_util
description: A simple dart API with a complete set of date helper methods  
             not available in the DateTime API hence, production is 
             made easier when working with dates.
version: 0.1.4
homepage: https://github.com/corpsgeek/Date-Utility
author: Adetu Ridwan, Egbesola Anthony <bethetechnology@gmail.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.20.1 <3.0.0'

#dependencies:
#  path: ^1.4.1

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^0.12.0
```

It seems that different sdk versions cause this error, as I use

```
environment:
      sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

and date_uril.dart uses

```
environment:
      sdk: '>=1.20.1 <3.0.0'
```

now haw can I handle this situation so that I can use this package in my app. thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked pub.dev page of `date_utils` it doesn't have a version 0.1.4

Comment: Looks like you are confusing `date_util` and `date_utils`. Also, why did you add it as a dev_dependency rather than a regular one?

Comment: @HasilT it has, here is the address: https://pub.dev/packages/date_util/versions

Comment: @RichardHeap  I don't understand what you said about adding as dev_dependency or regular, can you please give more info about what are each them? I think we should always edit dev_dependencies in pubspec.yaml file when adding a new external package to our project, or ide (I use VSCode) do that automatically

Comment: see: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies TL;DR move date-util up 7 lines - and spell it correctly (without the final 's')

Comment: @RichardHeap I have been careless, thank you